# IE/Edge profiler doesn't show js call stack

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, profiler

Like in the title, both my Edge and IE doesn't show any data in JS call stack tab in the Profiler tab in the dev tools. I have tried deselecting 'Disable script debugging (other)' and 'Disable debugging script (IE)' and restarting computer as well as disabling IE in system features and enabling it back.

Edit:
Needing it for the app im developing which is using webpack. I noticed that I cant see webpack/. catalog as well in Debugging tab -> Scripts section. Still, it seems that there is something wrong in my configuration, as my collegue have filled js call stack tab on her VM's IE.
Currently im downloading it to try it there

Comment: Try to reset the IE and MS Edge to see whether it helps to solve the issue or not.

Comment: Nope, it didn't :<

Comment: Try to check whether the issue happen with any random website or it just occur with any specific site. If there are any specific steps to reproduce the issue than let us know about that.Also try to inform us which exact OS build you are using for making this test? check whether there is any new Windows update is available or not. If available than install it.

Comment: I have checked some random pages with no success.Win 10 Pro 1903, build 18362.239. Always updating as soon as I see new update - installing new one right now.

Also, editing first post with more detail

Comment: In the original post, you said that there is something wrong in your configuration. I want to confirm with you that are you talking about the configuration of your site or configuration of IE? As soon as you reset the IE every settings get its default value.

Comment: With IE or system config, as same problem exists in Edge. I have downloaded the Windows VM image for hyper-v and this problem don't exists in there. Not a solution but a workaround